# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder error

Tags: java, json, search, gson

I'm trying to make an irc bot in java that uses the Google api to search for things. I found a tutorial that uses GSON and the program compiles just fine. When I try to actually use the bot I get the error.

My import:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
```

The line that is giving me the error

```
Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().create();
```

I am using this as a guide http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/json_to_java.php

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't do step 2 properly.

Include the gson library to your classpath.(Using an IDE you can add the gson.jar to your java project.)

If you are using an IDE, such as Eclipse and this project is a Java project (as opposed to a Maven project) then add the gson.jar to your lib folder.

Comment: ah, I'm doing this manually because I didn't really think it through when I started. This is how I'm including it           javac -classpath pircbot.jar;parser-sources.jar;googleapi.jar;C:\DESKTOP\MISC\xunbot\google-gson\*;. *.java